# multiseat, is it possible to access virtual terminals on any seat?

Tags: xorg, lightdm, multiseat

My current multiseat config works fine, except for one thing : I cant access virtual terminal on either seat.
I think it comes from the fact I launch X through my DM (LightDM) with the -sharevts switch, but unless I put this switch, I got the weird issue that seat1 gpu crashes when I logout seat0.
Here is my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[LightDM]
minimum-display-number=0
minimum-vt=7

[SeatDefaults]
#greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
user-session=lightdm-xsession
exit-on-failure=true
greeter-hide-users=false

[Seat:0]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :0 -keeptty -sharevts
xserver-layout=seat0
xdg-seat=seat0
[Seat:1]
xserver-command=/usr/bin/X :1 -keeptty -sharevts
xserver-layout=seat1
xdg-seat=seat1
```

now when looking in processes, I see the -novtswitch option enabled on seat0, I got no idea who puts it here though :

```
➜  ~  ps aux | grep '/bin/X'
root     11770  0.0  0.4 371940 60364 ?        Sl   13:48   0:00 /usr/bin/X :0 -keeptty -sharevts :0 -layout seat0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
lotso    12619  0.0  0.0  12724  2236 pts/2    S+   14:23   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn /bin/X
root     16612  0.0  0.2 305416 33252 ?        Sl   Apr06   0:00 /usr/bin/X :1 -keeptty -sharevts :1 -layout seat1 -seat seat1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp
```

Ideally I'd like to have access to vt1 to 6 on seat0 and that seat1 got only it's X server running. Is that achievable ?
Thanks for your help.